# How to Get Correct co-ordinates after zooming?

Tags: android, zooming

im using finger paint turtorial with

```
class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {


                mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            return true;
        }
    }
```

but after zooming canvas,my lines are not drawing at correct position on canvas?

Answer (score 0):

you have create logic like when you zooming then increase your canvas size also
like `canvasHeight=(canvasHeight*mScaleFactor);`